# Calling a getversion function from kernel32.dll on java

Tags: java, windows, function, dll

I'm trying to call a Getversion function from kernel32.dll on Java. I wish to run a Java app that runs that function. However, I'm finding the information available very confusing and it's getting me nowhere.

1. I've downloaded the JNA.jar file and added it to my build properties in my Java project.
2. I've put the kernel32.dll in the root directory of my Java project.

But from here I am clueless... I am a beginner programmer in Java (and everywhere else really). Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use JNI to call the dll file in java. JNI will be used for adding libraries inside java

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Shiram. However, from what I've been gathering online, it seems it's easier to use the JNA...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the kernel32.dll which is already setting up while your OS is running. 
Just keep in mind that there is the dll existed somewhere in your path.

The prototype of GetVersion function is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724439(v=vs.85).aspx) on the msdn site.

```
DWORD WINAPI GetVersion(void);
```

You can confirm that the function belongs to 'kernel32' function.

There are two ways of implementing this as far as i know.

First you can make a main entry like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        testGetVersion();
        testGetVersion2();
    }
```

The second method is rather simple than first one.

```
private static void testGetVersion2() {
        Function versionFunc = Function.getFunction("kernel32", "GetVersion");
        DWORD versionNum = null;

        versionNum = (DWORD)versionFunc.invoke(DWORD.class, null);


        System.out.println("Version is ... " + versionNum.toString());
    }
```

And let's talk this subject deeper..the first method like

```
private static void testGetVersion() {
        DWORD versionNum = Kernel32Me.INSTANCE.GetVersion();

        System.out.println("Version is ... " + versionNum.toString());
    }
```

So, you should have your own class for the windows system prototype.
The Kernel32Me interface might be a little bit complicated..

```
public interface Kernel32Me extends StdCallLibrary {
        final Kernel32Me INSTANCE 
            = (Kernel32Me) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32.dll", Kernel32Me.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

        DWORD GetVersion();

    }
```

I think you can have your OS version at this time.

It may be good point of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822087/what-to-use-instead-of-lptstr-in-java-jna/43841667#43841667).

Good luck.